# _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value) dart

Tags: flutter, dart

```
                     onTap: () async {
                        final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;
                        var lat = double.tryParse("-$detailCampus['latitude']")!;
                        var long = double.tryParse("$detailCampus['longitude']")!;
                        controller.animateCamera(
                          CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
                            CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, long), zoom: 18, tilt: 50, bearing: 45),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
```

my code has an error, i want to take **latitude and longitude** from my database. but i had problem **double** need null checker when i try to use null checker like this

```
var lat = double.tryParse("-$detailCampus['latitude']")!;
var long = double.tryParse("$detailCampus['longitude']")!;
```

then i try this one

```
CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat!, long!), zoom: 18, tilt: 50, bearing: 45),
```

but still error.

Comment: in which part you get your error? in pares code or the CameraPosition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var lat = double.tryParse("-${detailCampus['latitude']}") ?? 0;
var long = double.tryParse("${detailCampus['longitude']}") ?? 0;
```

Then

```
CameraPosition(target: LatLng(lat, long), zoom: 18, tilt: 50, bearing: 45),
```